# Database (database/db_intranet.sqlite) does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I managed to migrate and seed a sqlite database (located in database dir) by replacing the database block in .env with the following

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=database/db_intranet.sqlite
```

However when I want to make any operations to the database from the models I'm given this error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
Database (database/db_intranet.sqlite) does not exist.
```

Which is solved by changing the block to this

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=../database/db_intranet.sqlite
```

My question is, why? And what can I do so I don't have to constantly alter the .env file to work with the database?

Comment: Change from your `database.php` like `'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),`

Comment: I just tried changing  database_path() to /database/database.sqlite and ../database/database.sqlite and database/database.sqlite but is the same

Comment: Change `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),` instead of ``'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`` in your `database.php`

Comment: After change, run `php artisan cinfig:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` then serve

Comment: @sta I dont know why your answer was deleted but it did work after php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `database.php`  change :

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('db_intranet.sqlite')),
```

to:

```
'database' => database_path('db_intranet.sqlite'),
```

Instead of a relative path you need to use an absolute path in your **.env** file, as :

```
DB_DATABASE=/var/www/project/database/db_intranet.sqlite
```

On windows, like :

```
DB_DATABASE=C:\www\project\database\db_intranet.sqlite
```

After change, run **php artisan config:clear**  and **php artisan cache:clear** then serve it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use relative path in the .env file as

`DB_DATABASE=/var/www/project/database/db_intranet.sqlite` if you are using Ubuntu operating system.

if you are using windows system then you can use

`DB_DATABASE=C:\www\project\database\db_intranet.sqlite`

and in `config/database.php` you can use

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('db_intranet.sqlite')),
```